I need assistance with the error Proj_db in QGIS
I'm trying to merge 3 rasters to complete the map of a country but when i run the merge function on QGIS i obtain this error:
GDAL command:gdal_merge.py -separate -ot Float32 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 -o /private/var/folders/b_/8lp6_5sd08jcdq8f4fgxvhqh0000gn/T/processing_houwso/cc2e65bcbf0049a7a12775faa7d36667/OUTPUT.tif --optfile /private/var/folders/b_/8lp6_5sd08jcdq8f4fgxvhqh0000gn/T/processing_houwso/57158c118c454d4eb6f446acadede378/mergeInputFiles.txt
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
I've tried to locate the file on mac MAcOS but cannot find it. I've updated the QGIS software but also no results. Anyone know how to solve this issue? much appreciated!
